# Using jspm bundles in production, not development

Tags: django, deployment, bundle, jspm

I'm developing a web application. The front-end is done with Angular and ES 6, using jspm as a package manager. jspm is great.

Now it's time to consider deployment. Having very little experience with front-end deployment, I'm a bit lost. I used

```
jspm bundle-sfx app/module app.js --minify
```

to bundle all Javascript resources into one file.

My problem is this - I want to use the bundled js file only when deployed to an actual server. During development I'd much rather let jspm and System.js access the individual files. I couldn't figure out clean enough way to do that.

I'm using the Django development web server to serve pages in development, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up letting Django handle this in the html template. If DEBUG is False, I add the bundled js file.

I was hoping for a solution that doesn't require server-side intervention.